# Convert short PHP script to Python

Tags: php, python, converters

Being a pure Python Programmer, I need some help to: 
1) Make the PHP script read from a text file
2) Translate the PHP script to Python

Here is the PHP code:

```
function newlineEveryFive($str){ 
    $array = explode(" ", $str); 
    for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){ 
        if($i!=0 && $i%5==0) 
            $out .= "\n".$array[$i]." "; 
        else 
            $out .= $array[$i]." "; 
    } 
    return $out; 
}
```

Thank you to anyone who takes their time to help me :)

Comment: user2972339 : Do this and post the result:1) Make the PHP script read from a text file 2) Translate the PHP script to Python

Comment: The least you can do is read up or do a search on what is `explode` in PHP. Its called `split`. So use Python's own `split`. And i am sure you know how to read a for loop and what `i%5==0` is testing. The PHP code is rather easy to decipher and easy to translate to Python, if you are really a Python programmer.

Comment: i % 5 == 0 divides the variable i by 5 and checks whether the remainder is equal to 0

I know how line works, but my attempts at writing the Python script always don't work, e.g. only the first line is split

Comment: Sorry, we do not take requests. If you want to use PHP then learn to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is, in Python:

```
SSSSSSSSSSSSSsssssssssssssssss SSSSSSSSSSSSSSssssssssssssss
```

But really:

```
>>> lines = []
>>> for i in range(0,len(words),5):
    line = " ".join(words[i:i+5])
    lines.append(line)
>>> out = "\n".join(lines)
```

Comment: What should I define "words" as? The text from the file? Because right now, I'm getting this error:

for i in range(0,len(words),5):

NameError: name 'words' is not defined

Comment: Forgot, `words = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet thaumium ingot needs your attention placeholder text".split()`.

Comment: Thanks, it's almost perfect now :D. But one problem is that it is counting characters and spaces in the file, meaning instead of getting five words on a line, i get this:

  M 2 (i.e. *space* *space* M *space* 2)

And I need those spaces for future processing :(

Comment: Please read carefully, you need to know what you do, because Python is happy to index the text by characters, you need to `yr_string.split()` it beforehand.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YCJtYHmd I've posted the code and the output here, as to make reading easier. I have done the split, yet the output remains the same

Comment: Oh I'm sorry D: IT WORKS NOW :DDD Thank you :3